# Unanticipated Python Dictionary Behavior

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have this piece of code:

```
import time

d = dict()
for i in range(200000):
    d[i] = "DUMMY"

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(200000):
    for key in d:
        if len(d) > 1 or -1 not in d:
            break
    del d[i]

print("--- {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Why does this take ~15 seconds to run?

But, if I comment out `del d[i]` or the inner loop, it runs in ~0.1 seconds.

Comment: Even stranger, if I remove the `for key in d:` loop, it goes back to taking a fraction of a second!

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that at first.

Comment: I wonder if the iterator for `d` is cached, and using `del d[i]` forces a new iterator to be created each time through the outer loop.

Comment: Well, Raymond Hettinger and other core developers sometimes answer questions on this tag, so hopefully they will come around...

Comment: @chepner strangely, if I replace the for-lop with `iter(d)` it's still fast.

Comment: I'm assuming Python 3. What version exactly? I can reprduce on 3.8 and 3.5

Comment: Ah, it's the first call to `next` on the iterator that takes time; replace the loop with something like `di = iter(d); next(di)` and the running time goes back to 15 seconds.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, 3.8.1

Comment: I can reproduce with 2.7, so this looks version independent..

Comment: What could `dict_iterator.__next__` be doing that would slow down deletions?

Comment: Looking at the [current source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eb8ac57af26c4eb96a8230eba7492ce5ceef7886/Objects/dictobject.c#L3682) (Python 2.7 may be similar; I haven't looked), `dictiter_iternextvalue` can either get a value directly from a `ma_values` field, or it has to walk the `dict` to get the value. Something about `del d[i]` might switch from the fast path to the slow.

Comment: It looks like the `ma_values` path is for key-sharing dictionaries, usually used for object attribute dicts (which put their keys out into an object shared by all instances), not for normal dicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is caused by iterating over even one element (e.g. `next(iter(d))`) of a dictionary that was once large, but has been shrunk a great deal. This can be nearly slow as iterating over all of the dictionary items if you get unlucky with your hash values. And this code is very "unlucky" (predictably so, due to Python hash design).

The reason for the issue is that Python does not rebuild a dictionary's hash table when you remove items. So the hash table for a dictionary that used to have 200000 items in it, but which now has only 1 left is still has more than 200000 spaces in it (and probably more, since it was probably not entirely full at its peak).

When you're iterating the dictionary when it has all its values in it, finding the first one is pretty simple. The first one will be in one of the first few table entries. But as you empty out the table, more and more blank spaces will be at the start of the table and the search for the first value that still exists will take longer and longer.

This might be even worse given that you're using integer keys, which (mostly) hash to themselves (only `-1` hashes to something else). This means that the first key in the "full" dictionary will usually be `0`, the next `1`, and so on. As you delete the values in increasing order, you'll be very precisely removing the earliest keys in the table first, and so making the searches maximally worse.

Answer (score 4):

It's because this

```
for key in d:
    if len(d) > 1 or -1 not in d:
        break
```

will break on the first iteration, so your inner loop is basically a no-op.

Adding `del[i]` makes it do some real work, which takes time.

**Update:** well the above is obviously way to simplistic :-)

The following version of your code shows the same characteristic:

```
import time
import gc
n = 140000

def main(d):
    for i in range(n):
        del d[i]        # A
        for key in d:   # B
            break       # B

import dis
d = dict()
for i in range(n):
    d[i] = "DUMMY"


print dis.dis(main)
start_time = time.time()
main(d)
print("--- {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Using iterkeys doesn't make a difference.

If we plot the run time on different sizes of `n` we get (n on the x-axis, seconds on the y-axis):

[image]

so clearly something exponential going on.

Deleting line (A) or lines (B) removes the exponential component, although I'm not sure why.

**Update 2:** Based on @Blckknght's answer, we can regain some of the speed by infrequently rehashing the items:

```
def main(d):
    for i in range(n):
        del d[i]
        if i % 5000 == 0:
            d = {k:v for k, v in d.items()}
        for key in d:
            break
```

or this:

```
def main(d):
    for i in range(n):
        del d[i]
        if i % 6000 == 0:
            d = {k:v for k, v in d.items()}
        try:
            iter(d).next()
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

takes under half the time of the original on large n (the bump at 130000 is consistent over 4 runs..).

[image]

Comment: Weird, if I delete the inner for loop, the `for key in d:` and simply do `del d[i]`, it takes a fraction of a second...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes, why is that?

Comment: This doesn't really explain why removing the *inner* loop but keeping the `del d[i]` it goes back being fast. I can't explain this

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some performance cost to accessing the keys as a whole after deleting an item.  This cost is not incurred when you do direct accesses so, my guess is that the dictionary flags its key list as dirty when an item is removed and  waits for a reference to the key list before updating/rebuilding it.

This explains why you don't get a performance hit when you remove the inner loop (you're not causing the key list to be rebuilt). It also explains why the loop is fast when you remove the `del d[i]` line (you're not flagging the key list for rebuilding).